# Value of session-timeout getting overrided. What are the ways to set the session value

Tags: java, session, tomcat, session-variables, sap-commerce-cloud

Application has

`<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>`

set in web.xml.

I have changed it to

`<session-timeout>2</session-timeout>`

in all the web.xml files. 
But still, request.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() returns 30 mintues.

The setMaxInactiveInterval(int) isn't used anywhere in Java. Any other ways this  can be over-ridden. Using Tomcat Server.

Comment: Restart your server and deploye the your application another time

Comment: Yes, start a system update.

Comment: @HristoStaykov In hybris, changes in web.xml need system update as well ?

Comment: @YoucefLaidani Have tried ant clean all and started already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybris has been added configuration property to adjust session timeout.

Try changing the property in `local.properties` file.

```
default.session.timeout = 120
```

You can check the default value in platform/project.properties file.

```
# The default session timeout (in seconds).
# If you specify 0 or less, the session will never timeout
default.session.timeout=3600
```